# Mismatch between my form validators (len in python and length in javascript)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using formencode in the backend side as a validation and form generation package. And on the front end side I am using require.js.

Backend:

```
class RatingOnLocation(Schema):
    filter_extra_fields = True
    allow_extra_fields = True

    rating_text = validators.UnicodeString(not_empty=True, max=2000, strip=True)
    rating = validators.Int(not_empty=True, min=1, max=5)
```

front-end:

```
init = function () {

        // Add Validation rules to the review form
        $form.validate({
            rules: {
                rating_text: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 2000
                }
```

The validation is somehow messed since through the debugging the length of the text in javascript gives 2000 whereas the len in python gives 2012.

Do you know what is going on here? I thought maybe it is an encoding issue

By the way I am using python 2.7